# How to delete the first argument in arguments object?

Tags: javascript, object, arguments

I need to remove the first item in the `arguments` object so that my `let args` variable equals to all the following arguments.
How can I do it?

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  let myArr = arguments[0];
  let args = arguments;
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Comment: Is not very clear what you need here.

Comment: `arguments = arguments.splice(0, 1)` is the thing you need inside `destroyer()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `slice` to retrieve the arguments past the first, and use rest parameters instead of a single `arr` in your function argument, if you can - many linters recommend against using `arguments`, and using that keyword is not necessary here:

```js
function destroyer(...args) {
  const otherArgs = args.slice(1);
  console.log('length: ' + otherArgs.length, 'items: ' + otherArgs);
}
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

If you want a reference to the first argument as well, use rest parameters *after* collecting the first `arr` into a variable:

```js
function destroyer(arr, ...otherArgs) {
  console.log('arr: ' + arr);
  console.log('length: ' + otherArgs.length, 'items: ' + otherArgs);
}
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way:

```
function destroyer(...arr) {
  arr.shift();
  console.log( arr ); // 2,3
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```